# Give permissions to just one EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-organizations

I have several EC2 instances in my AWS amazon account. I have one specific EC2 instance that I want an outsourcer to use (stop,start, manage security group, resize disk space, etc).

I tried to do it with IAM policies, but from what I see, the DescribeInstances allows the user to see all instances in my account. And when I try to edit the policy for a specific resource it shows error because it DescribeInstances is not a resource-level policy, so it must have Resource '*'.

I was thinking maybe allow him access to a different region, and put the instance there. Another option is using organizations (a little complex, but looks promising, would be happy to understand if this is the way to go).

Am I missing something? What is the best solution to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to give the outsourcer permission to call AWS services in your account, then **from a security perspective**, it would be much safer to **put those resources in a child account**.

That way, you are guaranteed that their credentials are not able to impact any of your other resources and services.

The alternative would be way too complex to manage. For example, security groups can be associated with many instances and one instance can have many security groups. That would not be possible to code within an IAM policy.

Comment: just to confirm: with child account you mean to use organizations?

Comment: I strongly recommend John's solution. IMHO everyone should have at least two accounts with AWS. One account for production resources. Another account for testing and development. When working with outside resources use a third account. We even use separate accounts for employees (developers). 10 years ago we did not do that and we had lots of accidents with the wrong resources being deleted, modifying the wrong resources, etc. Just simplifying billing and resource allocation makes multiple accounts worth it.

Comment: Yes, by "child account" I mean a separate account under AWS Organizations. Traditionally accounts were hierarchical (hence 'child account'), but Organizations calls them _member accounts_.